# Why True for [1] < [1, 2] in Python

Tags: list, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 python list objects with integers.  I understand that python uses lexicographical comparison.  While doing so I came across this scenario. when I compared `[1] < [1, 2]` python returned True.  Shouldn't that be False?

```
[1] < [1] # returns False
[1, 2] < [1] # returns False as well
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should return False, please?

Comment: "lexicographical comparison" is also known as dictionary sort. Do you understand that in a dictionary, "cat" comes before "catamaran"?

Comment: Got it.  It compares the length of the list in addition to the item value.  Thank you for your response